# python xlrd using thread behavior

Tags: python, multithreading, xlrd

Does anyone had problem with xlrd library and threading? Why open a xlsx file in sequence is faster than open it in thread?

My sample.slsx is very simple, number from 1 to 10000 (rows) from column A to Z

Here is my code:

```
from optparse import OptionParser

import threading
import xlrd
import datetime
import time

###############################################################################

class ReadFileXlsx():
    def __init__(self, xlsxFile):
        self.__xlsx_file = xlsxFile

    def read_file(self):
        wbHandler = xlrd.open_workbook(self.__xlsx_file)
        #time.sleep(3)

###############################################################################

class ReadFileXlsxThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, xlsxFile):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.__file_handler = ReadFileXlsx(xlsxFile)

    def run(self):
        self.__file_handler.read_file()

###############################################################################

def run1(filename, max):
    d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    for index in range(0, max):
        d2 = datetime.datetime.now()
        handler = ReadFileXlsx(filename)
        handler.read_file()
        d3 = datetime.datetime.now()
        print "run1() - " + str(index) + " - time = " + str(d3-d2)

    d4 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print "run1() - TOTAL time = " + str(d4-d1)

def run2(filename, max):
    d1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    threads = []

    for index in range(0, max):
        d2 = datetime.datetime.now()
        handler = ReadFileXlsxThread(filename)
        handler.start()
        d3 = datetime.datetime.now()
        print "run2() - " + str(index) + " - time = " + str(d3-d2)

        # Add threads to thread list
        threads.append(handler)

    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for t in threads:
        t.join()    

    d4 = datetime.datetime.now()
    print "run2() - TOTAL time = " + str(d4-d1)

def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest = "xlsxfile", 
                    help = "", 
                    metavar = "FILE")                     
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if not options.xlsxfile:
        print "please type python " \
              "ReadFileXlsx.py --file=[xlsxfilename]"
    else:

        run1(options.xlsxfile, 10)
        run2(options.xlsxfile, 10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the output is:

```
>main.py --file=sample.xlsx
run1() - 0 - time = 0:00:02.489000
run1() - 1 - time = 0:00:02.272000
run1() - 2 - time = 0:00:02.516000
run1() - 3 - time = 0:00:02.259000
run1() - 4 - time = 0:00:02.310000
run1() - 5 - time = 0:00:02.265000
run1() - 6 - time = 0:00:02.285000
run1() - 7 - time = 0:00:02.322000
run1() - 8 - time = 0:00:02.254000
run1() - 9 - time = 0:00:02.377000
run1() - TOTAL time = 0:00:23.360000
run2() - 0 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - 1 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - 2 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - 3 - time = 0:00:00.001000
run2() - 4 - time = 0:00:00.001000
run2() - 5 - time = 0:00:00.002000
run2() - 6 - time = 0:00:00.001000
run2() - 7 - time = 0:00:00.001000
run2() - 8 - time = 0:00:00.001000
run2() - 9 - time = 0:00:00.001000
run2() - TOTAL time = 0:00:44.256000
```

If i change the implemenation of ReadFileXlsx.read_file()
from

```
wbHandler = xlrd.open_workbook(self.__xlsx_file)
```

to

```
time.sleep(3)
```

I got the expected behavior. Output:

```
>main.py --file=sample.xlsx
run1() - 0 - time = 0:00:03.001000
run1() - 1 - time = 0:00:03
run1() - 2 - time = 0:00:03.001000
run1() - 3 - time = 0:00:03
run1() - 4 - time = 0:00:03
run1() - 5 - time = 0:00:03
run1() - 6 - time = 0:00:03.001000
run1() - 7 - time = 0:00:03.001000
run1() - 8 - time = 0:00:03
run1() - 9 - time = 0:00:03
run1() - TOTAL time = 0:00:30.009000
run2() - 0 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - 1 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - 2 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - 3 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - 4 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - 5 - time = 0:00:00.001000
run2() - 6 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - 7 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - 8 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - 9 - time = 0:00:00
run2() - TOTAL time = 0:00:03.008000
```

I think it is something with xlrd. Could anyone help?

Regards

Comment: I'd make a guess that since all the threads are trying to access the same space in memory all the threads end up waiting their turn for the IO operations.

Comment: After taking a look at the source code it does some timing of its own, you can look at `b.load_time_stage_1` and `b.load_time_stage_2` of the book that is returned from `xlrd.open_workbook`, it might be useful to you.

Comment: thank you, i will take a look on that